# Is this possible to get thread leakage information via JMX?

Tags: java, threadpool, jmx, resource-leak

If my thread pool is exposed over JMX then is there any way to get information about thread leakage . That is which MBean will tell me that thread leakage has occured?

Comment: check on this link?http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/01/practical-guide-to-using-jmx-platform-mbeans.html